# CSS - Change color of dropdown menu while hovering child menu items

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar with html like this:

```
<html>
  <nav class="mainMenu1">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Options</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Option 1</li>
          ...
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</html>
```

I need to change the background color of the li element with class: menu-item while the sub menu items(also li) are being hovered over by the mouse ... here is my css so far:

```
nav.mainMenu1 ul li.active > a {
    background: #044668 !important; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#044668, #008bbc) !important; /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#044668, #008bbc) !important; /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#044668, #008bbc) !important; /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#044668, #008bbc) !important; /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with the complete css you have. Build a working example (snippet/jsfiddle) to show what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS there is no way to select parent element or previous selector, but you can do a trick using `:after` pseudoelement

```css
.menu-item{
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu:after{
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  
  background: #044668 !important;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#044668, #008bbc) !important;
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#044668, #008bbc) !important;
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#044668, #008bbc) !important;
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#044668, #008bbc) !important;
  /* Standard syntax */
  

}

.sub-menu:hover:after{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="mainMenu1">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">Options</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
        <li>Option 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```